# Why this way for the recursion and what does it mean?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this piece of code

```
def listSum(ls):
    if not ls:
        return 0

    return ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])
```

Two things bug me a bit

1. `if not ls:` - What does it mean? As nothing has been specified, what is it looking for?
2. `ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])` - I've tried using `listSum(ls[0:])` only and I have running error. Why? Why should I stick to `ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])`?

Comment: 1. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing, it's the idiom for *"if `ls` is empty"*. 2. If you pass the whole list (`ls[0:]` or just `ls[:]`) into the recursive call, how will it ever become empty?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Should I close my question?

Comment: Empty containers are `False`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the grammatical amendments and removing the `hard time` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine it's called...

```
listSum([3, 5, 3, 7])
```

It get down to...

```
return ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])
```

...which is evaluated as...

```
return 3 + listSum([5, 3, 7])
```

Then `listSum([5, 3, 7])` as `5 + listsum([3, 7])`.

Then `listSum([3, 7])` as `3 + listsum([7])`.

Then `listSum([7])` as `7 + listsum([])`, which is where the `not ls` kicks in and returns `0`.

So, the complete thing is then evaluated as...

```
3 + 5 + 3 + 7 + 0
```

Notes:

- `listSum(ls[1:])` is shortening the list each time - reducing the complexity of the remaining problem, until an invocation of `listSum` receives an empty list: the trivial case that `if not ls: return 0` handles
- recursive solutions are often made up of two parts: a solution for the simplest possible input (or sometimes, a couple very simple cases), and something saying how to take an arbitrarily complicated input and reduce it to a formula making one or more recusive calls that are each at least a little bit simpler, always moving towards that simplest possible input
- *"I've tried using `listSum(ls[0:])`"* - `ls[0:]` returns a copy of `ls` - it would ask for the same list to be processed ad infinitum
- it's arguably more intuitive to explicitly handle a list of one element - `if len(ls) == 1: return ls[0]` - but then if anyone called `listSum([])` you'd try to access `[0]` (in the other code below the `if`) and raise an exception; handling the empty list makes the function easier to use *if* `listSum([])` returning `0` is sane for your application, but on the other hand having `listSum([])` raise an exception might uncover bugs where lists are unexpectedly empty - you can decide which is more useful to you; happily if you do handle the empty-list case, `len(ls) == 1` case then "just works" with the same recursion logic

Comment: Hi @tony-d, let's say I'm stupid and I want to keep carrying `listSum(ls[0]:)`, what would me prevent me in doing so?

Comment: @AndyK the system recursion limit? Again, if you're not shortening the list of each recursive call, you never reach the terminating condition of an empty list.

Comment: Hi @AndyK - recursive calls do need some way to know when to stop, otherwise they'll either hang the program or crash when the stack is exhausted, as jonrsharpe mentions.

Comment: @TonyD many thanks for your time and patience. You've totally nailed my questions. Kudos

Comment: @AndyK: you're welcome.  Recursion does a lot of peoples' heads in - mine too at times - so if I save anyone a little grief, great.  Cheers.